# Sine-Gordon Equation application

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Is it true that Sine-Gordon is satisfied for geodesics on  the central Pseudosphere ( rotated surface of Tractrix)? If so, please cite text-book or article references. Searching for it in references suggested by  [Lucas Lavoyer](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sapm198674155/abstract)

Chebychev scissorde/diamond cell Net for hyperbolic lines on a Beltrami pseudosphere are given by:

$$ \alpha''(s)=sin ( \alpha) $$ where $\alpha$ =  $2 \psi$,$\psi$  is angle between geodesic and v= constant parameter lines.

I just discovered the above to be true but to check old literature an access to thorough academic  base is lacking.

( Sine-Gordon ChebychevNet for asymptotic lines are well known, but not referring to it now).

I am adding Mathematica generated image and relation for polar plot in this finding, $( r,\theta, z) $ are cylindrical co-ordinates:

$$ (\theta/r_{oH})^2 = 1/r_{oE}^2 - 1/r^2 $$

where $ r_{oE} $ is the minimum (geodesic lines are orthogonal to meridian here, it is the Clairaut's constant   $ r*sin\psi $ radius and  $r_{oH}$ is maximum pseudospherical cuspidal radius at equator. These are the invariants in elliptic and hyperbolic branches of non-euclidean geometry that we are able to see here *together* on this pseudospherical surface of revolution. Image verifies circumferential disposition at minimum radius before going to cuspidal equator radius $r_{oH}$

If $\psi_{min}$ is angle where the geodesic meets cuspidal equator,
$$ sin \psi_{min}= r_{oE} /r_{oH}$$

Derivation is simple and straightforward. Dropping (s) as for pure functions of arc length s.

Liouville's formula for a geodesic on surface of revolution:

$ \psi'$ =- $ sin\psi$ $sin\phi /r $ ;                                   (1)

For a tractrix meridian : $ 1/r_{oH} = sin \phi /r $  ;               (2)

plug above into (1) to get $ \psi' =-sin \psi/ r_{oH} $ ;             (3)

Differentiate the above and plug into the same from above for $ \psi'$ to get

$ \psi''$= $sin \psi$ $cos \psi$ $ /r_{oH}^2$   ; $ 2 \psi = \alpha $ ;        (4)

yields Sine-Gordon $ \alpha''= sin ( \alpha)/r_{oH}^2 $ for cusped pseudosphere radius $ r_{oH}$.

EDIT1:

So why is it that the *nature of geodesic*s whether hyperbolic negative or elliptic Riemannian positive, *never influences Sine-Gordon*?

Earlier I was under the impression that a Chebychev net can form or essentially get defined by asymptotic hyperbolic geodesic zero normal curvature lines *only*, which is *found untrue* from present evidence.

Thanks in advance for any information/insights including any non-rotational surfaces in $ \mathbb R^3.$

[image: Geodesics on pseudosphere]

Comment: @ Lucas Lavoyer Thanks for the link. Can you please refer me to the equation  in the cited link?